# PHP wont update/insert

Tags: php

So here is my code, have no ide why its not working have been looking at it for hours, points to anyone who can figure it out. The variables are passed fine, and server connection made. The error message the browser gives is,

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username'', 'Saturday 20th of August 2011 02:02:22 PM', 'first', 'last', 'ssn' at line 2

i replaced the variable data back with the variable name so you can get an idea, so where is says first, the browser actually shows the first name i entered.

Thanks!

```
$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS['username'] = $username;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
 $Todaysdate = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
 $firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
 $lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
 $ssn = $_REQUEST['ssn'];  
 $street = $_REQUEST['street']; 
 $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
 $zip = $_REQUEST['zip'];
 $phone1 = $_REQUEST['phone1'];
 $phone2 = $_REQUEST['phone2']; 
 $hdhas = $_REQUEST['hdhas'];
 $mi= $_REQUEST['mi'];





 $query = ("INSERT INTO Members (username, email, todaysdate, firstname, lastname, ssn,       street, city, zip, phone1, phone2, hdhas, mi)
 VALUES('$username','$email', '$Todaysdate', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$ssn', '$street', '$city', '$zip', '$phone1', '$phone2', '$hdhas', '$mi')");



 $checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Members WHERE username='$username'"); 


 if(mysql_num_rows($checkuser)>0)
{
 mysql_query("UPDATE Members SET email='$email', username='$username', todaysdate='$Todaysdate', firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', ssn='$ssn',  street='$street', city='$city', zip='$zip', phone1='$phone1', phone2='$phone2',  hdhas='$hdhas', mi='$mi' WHERE username = '$username'");
 } 

else {
mysql_query($query);
}

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
```

Comment: `$email` is a full query of its own. Also, important reading: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Welcome MysqlInjection, come and feel like at home :)! Read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: you have SQL injection holes in that code as big as Jupiter. Maybe you accidentally inserted some bad values in there (i.e. containing at least `'`). __LE__: Oh I spotted it: `[..]the right syntax to use near 'username''` <-- the inserted value is `username'`, which breaks the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Username is probably `username'`. Try to add mysql_real_escape_string() around your variables and read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)